# Push a UITableViewController onto a ViewController's UITableView

Tags: swift

I have researched this question but have not been able to come up with an answer after about an hour.  I have a `CardTableView` in a `ViewController` as the root and a second tableview with identifier `workTableView`.  I want to push `workTableView` onto `CardTableView` when a cell is selected and send an array to the `workTableView`.  I want to do this with a show segue.

Here is what I have tried in the `ViewController` that contains `CardTableView`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)


    let vc = UIStoryboard(name:"Workout", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "workTableView") as! TableViewController
print("selected")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

I created the `workTableView` in storyboard, but would like to create it programmatically eventually.

Comment: Delete `self.window!.rootViewController = nav1` and `self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()`. By the way, why do you need to follow this approach? You can just `present` your view controller when a cell is selected.

Comment: I'd recommend going through a few simple tutorials about presenting view controllers

Comment: @nayem I don't think I can `present` because the root view is not a controller, it is inside a controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `tableView(_:didSelectRowAT:)` method with this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Workout", bundle: nil)
    let nextScene = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondTableViewControllerStoryboardIdentifier") as! TableViewController // TableViewController <- must be changed to the name of the Second View Controller class

    nextScene.dataToPass = something you want to pass // dataToPass is the variable that you declare in your Second View Controller

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextScene, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify this question enough.  See my edit.  Actually, I only have a `UITableView`.  That tableview is in a `UIViewController`.  would I still override this in the `UITableView` or do I need to change it to a `UITableViewController`?

Comment: See my edit. Delete `override` keyword. @defoification

Comment: and in what class do I put this method in, `ViewController` or `UITableView`?

Comment: I think you are missing something. You are missing the basic logic needed. You can go through this [sample project](https://github.com/M-I-N/TableViewDemo)